# use JAXB to unmarshal element with duplicate ID

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm using JAXB to unmarshal an XML file.

Below is the xml content

```
<Cat id="1234">
  <FD id="1"/>
  <DC id="1" >
    <description>
      ABCD
    </description>
  </DC>
  <DC id="2" FD="1">
    <description>
      Optional
    </description>
  </DC>
</Cat>
```

As you can see, for `FD id="1"`, `DC id="1"`, both is having same ID, when unmarshal using jaxb, it hit error for `DC id = "2"`

> DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: The type of the field is class FD, but the type of the object is DC

I think it is due to in `DC id ="2"`, the attribute of `FD="1"` is mistaken map to DC instead of FD, as both is having same ID, anyway to solve this if xml can't be change?

Comment: Do you have a schema (XSD) that describes the structure of this XML? If the `id` attribute is defined with the standard schema type `xsd:ID` then it is actually invalid to have two elements in the XML with the same ID value - ID values must be unique within an XML document. This means that your XML is invalid, and JAXB cannot parse it correctly.

Comment: I can't find XSD for this XML, but the id attribute need to be unique, even across different type of element(in this case, DC and FD)?

Comment: Yes, if it is an `xsd:ID` then the value must be unique across the whole document, no matter if the elements are of different types.

Comment: Tried to generate xsd from correspond java class, and yes, it is xsd:ID for both DC and FD.

Comment: If that's the case, any specific class i can override, to allow such behaviour(match with ID + class type) instead of merely ID only?